# Javascript remove style to correct layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, inline

I have spent quite some time looking into this however, I repeatedly find a problem with every approach I have tried. I am using a slightly modified version of WordPress that removes the 'wp-' from URL's and some file/folder names. This works in every aspect other than the TinyMCE editor which is displaying the toolbar vertically. I have found that removing the elements inline CSS solves this problem. The code below is HTML code for the editor:

```
<div id="wp-content-editor-container" class="wp-editor-container”>
 <div id="ed_toolbar" class="quicktags-toolbar" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 0px;">
```

What I am looking for is a way to remove the section:

```
style="position:absolute; top: 0px; width: 0px;"
```

From the element. Originally I attempted to remove it from WordPress it's self however, I have been unable to find where it is being generated. I have tried a few methods using Javascript however, they generate errors and/or do not work. I will however say, that it may simply be something that I am doing as I have no experience with Javascript. I have tried the following approaches.

---

The first attempt was to include the following Javascript as a file:

```
var toolbar=document.getElementById("ed_toolbar");
toolbar.style.position=null;
toolbar.style.width=null;
toolbar.style.min-width=null;
```

However, this produced the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

---

So I altered the code to this:

```
var toolbar=document.getElementById("ed_toolbar");
toolbar.removeAttribute("style");
```

However, this produced the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null
```

---

Any ideas on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you wait until document is loaded? Sounds like ed_toolbar does not exists when you try to remove the attribute. Anyway, you could solve this via CSS, simply reset the styles as you want and add !important to the rules.

Comment: editor gets inserted asynchronously. This seems like a lot of over kill for something that could be done using straight css over ride

Comment: Is the tinymce editor inside of an iframe?

Comment: Your first code is probably what you want, but instead of setting the properties to `null`, set them to `""`.  Also, instead of `min-width` it should be `minWidth`. And make sure you put your script at the very end of the page(s), or else wrap them in a "ready" or "load" handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
on window load

```
$("#ed_toolbar").removeAttr("style"); or
$("#ed_toolbar").attr('style',null);
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j7krt3ac/1)

Comment: This probably won't work, as I think browsers won't let you get rid of the entire `style` object of an element.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use jquery and you are not sure that the element has been added after the page has originally loaded you can first select the div element that is one level above it. Which would be the div with an id of wp-content-editor-container in your example.

Javascript/JQuery:

```
    //remove the style from the #ed_toolbar div element
    $("#wp-content-editor-container #ed_toolbar").attr("style","");
```

Now if you aren't sure if #wp-content-editor is present when the page first loads then you can you the following code instead:

```
    //remove the style from the #ed_toolbar div element
    $("body #ed_toolbar").attr("style","");
```